# How to limit `mpl_connect` to an `axes` instead of a whole `figure`?

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, widget, interactive

I am coding a program where the user can interactively modify a plot. I am using 3 `mpl_connect` functions (`key_press_event` `button_press_event` `button_release_event`) plus 4 text boxes (`mwidgets.TextBox`).

Each time I type text to the text boxes, the process is slow and I think it is because when I click and write on a text box, it **needlessly** triggers the 3 "mpl connections" (`key_press_event` `button_press_event` `button_release_event`).

The 3 text boxes are outside the "axes object" and so I wonder if there is a way to limit the "mpl conections" to within the axis of interest only. That is, instead of coding the following:

```
cid1 = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onPressKey)
cid2 = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onPressButton)
cid3 = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', onReleaseButton)
```

to code something like (note the substitution of `canvas` for `axes`):

```
cid1 = figure.axes.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onPressKey)
cid2 = figure.axes.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onPressButton)
cid3 = figure.axes.mpl_connect('button_release_event', onReleaseButton)
```

Is there some workaround?

Any comment is welcome!

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible, but you don't provide the code for the functions `onPressKey` and others. Could you test which Axes object fired the event and return immediately if not the plotting one?

Comment: You write that you "think it is because when I click and write on a text box, it needlessly triggers the 3 "mpl connections" <- did you verify this, e.g. with a print statement inside `onPressKey()` functions? Also, could you use the `get_active()` method of the various widgets to determine whether input should go to the TextBox or the canvas?

Comment: @DizietAsahi - The functions`onPressKey`, `onPressButton`, `onReleaseButton` simply return the value of the pressed keyboard key or mouse button, which is actually an immediate return. @Asmus - Yes, I verified it just as you said. As I am typing on the text box, the function `onPressKey` is printing each one of the entered characters, which is unnecessary since I only use the value of the pressed keyboard key when I am hovering over the axes containing the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this simplistic example, and watch what the `print` statements return:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
t = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, 0.001)
s = t ** 2
initial_text = "t ** 2"
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)

def submit(text):
    ydata = eval(text)
    l.set_ydata(ydata)
    ax.set_ylim(np.min(ydata), np.max(ydata))
    plt.draw()

def onPressKey(event):
    print('you pressed key {0} in ax {1}'.format( event.key, event.inaxes ))
    if event.inaxes in [ax]:
        print("in ax")
    elif event.inaxes in [fig.axes[1]]:
        print("in cid1")
    else:
        print("outside")


axbox = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.075])
text_box = TextBox(axbox, 'Evaluate', initial=initial_text)
text_box.on_submit(submit)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onPressKey)

plt.show()
```

If you hover your mouse over the "plot region" (i.e. `ax`, or `fig.axes[0]`), every key you press will trigger the default keybindings (i.s. <kbd>s</kbd> triggers the save dialog).

The `onPressKey(event)` handler can already be used to decide what to do with this input, since it is aware of `event.inaxes`, i.e. where your mouse was during the `key_press_event`. 
Note however, that once you click inside the `TextBox` widget, it will capture your input (i.e. <kbd>s</kbd> gets written in there, no save dialog is triggered). 
If you now move your mouse *outside of the texbox*, the `onPressKey(event)` handler will still let you know that your *mouse* was within `ax` during text input (or perhaps "outside"), but this does *not change the fact* that the `TextBox` widget still captures your input, until you e.g. press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

**The short answer:** you don't want to connect the `key_press_event` to a specific axis, but rather want to let the `onPressKey(event)` handler, well *handle it*. Each keystroke should register as *one key_press_event*, so this will likely not be the culprit in your case (well unless your actual code is e.g. set up to do some expensive calculations on e.g. key <kbd>e</kbd> down, and you have *forgotten* to click inside the `TextBox` first.)